# Associating numbers with different words python

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe (df9), that has several columns, one of which is "ASSET_CLASS", and I also have a variable called "terms". ASSET_CLASS is made up of different names, whereas "terms" is numbers. I want to be able to create a new row in the dataframe that outputs different numbers per row based on the corresponding asset class and # of terms. For example, if Asset_Class is 'A' in a row, and #terms is between 30 and 60 for that row, I want my new column to output the number 5 for that row. Or if Asset_Class is 'A' and #terms is between 0 and 30, the new column shoots out 3 for that row. Or if Asset Class is 'B', and terms is between 30 and 60, then the output in the new column for that row is 8. Anyone have a good idea of how to do this? I was thinking maybe if, else statements, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Use ````replace```` and ````between````: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html

Comment: you can use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to create a list of the conditions you've laid out above, and what values you should assign when the first condition in that list evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [numpy.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html). To match your first two examples, the following code should add a new column called 'newcol' to your data frame, matching your first two cases, and putting a value of -1 everywhere not covered by explicitly defined cases.

```
ac = df9.ASSET_CLASS
t = df9.terms
condlist = [(ac=='A') & (t>=30) & (t<60), (ac=='A') & (t>=0) & (t<30)]
choicelist = [5, 3]
df9['newcol'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=-1)
```